# Simplifying/computing an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

I am attempting to compute some expectation value in a physics problem. I have computed that given $\psi_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin(n\pi x/a)$, we get
$$\phi_n(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^a\psi_n(x)e^{-ikx}dx=\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi a}}\frac{a}{a^2k^2-n^2\pi^2}e^{-ika}(-e^{ika}n\pi+n\pi\cos(n\pi)+iak\sin(n\pi))$$
My goal is to find the expectation of $k$, which is computed as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty k\phi^*_n(k)\phi(k)dk$. I have verified that my computation for $\phi_n(k)$ is correct, and  hence $\phi_n^*(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi a}}\frac{a}{a^2k^2-n^2\pi^2}e^{ika}(-e^{-ika}n\pi+n\pi\cos(n\pi)-iak\sin(n\pi))$. This leads to a rather convoluted expression for $\phi^*_n(k)\phi_n(k)$:
$$\frac{1}{\pi a}\frac{a^2}{(a^2k^2-n^2\pi^2)^2}(-e^{ika}n\pi+n\pi\cos(n\pi)+iak\sin(n\pi))(-e^{-ika}n\pi+n\pi\cos(n\pi)-\\iak\sin(n\pi))$$
which results in $$\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{a}{(n^2\pi^2-a^2k^2)^2}(a^2k^2\sin^2(n\pi)+n^2\pi^2\sin^2(ak)+n^2\pi^2\cos^2(ak)-2\pi^2n^2\cos(n\pi)\cos(ak)-2\pi akn\sin(n\pi)\sin(ak)+\pi^2n^2\cos^2(n\pi))$$
which "simplifies" to the following expression
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{a}{(n^2\pi^2-a^2k^2)^2}(n^2\pi^2+a^2k^2\sin^2(\pi n)+\pi^2n^2\cos^2(\pi n)-2\pi^2n^2\cos(\pi n)\cos(ak)-2\pi akn\sin(\pi n)\sin(ak))$$
Relabeling  to make it look a little less messy, $p=ak$ and $q=n\pi$, this reads
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{a}{(q^2-p^2)^2}(q^2+p^2\sin^2(q)+q^2\cos^2(q)-2q^2\cos(q)\cos(p)-2pq\sin(q)\sin(p))$$
However, this expression still seems completely unworkable to me. If I want to integrate this (multiplied by $p$, since I want the expectation) with respect to $p$, one of the integrals is going to be
$$\frac{-2aq}{\pi}\sin(q)\int\frac{p^2}{(q^2-p^2)^2}\sin(p)dp$$
I do not know how to manipulate an integral like this to solve it analytically. In fact, I am not even sure if this is feasible. Did I make a mistake simplifying this expression somewhere along the way, ending up with a more convoluted integral than I really need? If not, would anyone be able to provide me with a tool to solve these integrals?

Comment: Have you tried to use $n\in\mathbb Z$? Then $\sin n\pi=0$ and $\cos n\pi=(-1)^n$

Comment: That is very observant, or very unobservant of me. It has been a long time since I've done trig integrals and I think you might have just saved me.

Comment: @Andrei I guess $\displaystyle n = 1,2,3,\ldots ,\quad n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq\ 1}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin You are probably right

Comment: @Andrei Because that's the $\displaystyle 1\mathrm{D}$-$\displaystyle  square\ well$ in $\displaystyle\left[0,a\right]$.

Comment: That's exactly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @Andrei's comment, the expression simplifies to
$$
\phi^*_n\phi_n= 
\begin{cases}
    \frac{2}{\pi}a(1-\cos(p))(\frac{q}{q^2-p^2})^2,& \text{if } n\text{ is even}\\
    \frac{2}{\pi}a(1+\cos(p))(\frac{q}{q^2-p^2})^2,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
from which the expectation of $k^2$ can be solved using the identity $\int_{-\infty}^\infty p^2(1\pm\cos(p))(\frac{q}{q^2-p^2})^2dp=\mp \frac{\pi q}{2}(\sin(q)+q\cos(q))$, and the expectation of $k$ using the symmetry of the integrand. Thanks to him for pointing out my oversight.